# Is there ever a situation where an infinite loop may be desired?

Tags: algorithm, loops, infinite-loop

Infinite loops are taught as evil. Is there ever a good use?

When coding them by accident, the CPU peaks and I imagine memory does too, especially if assigning variables inside the loop.

If there is a good use, how are those issues prevented?

Comment: Is there a good use? I don't think there is.

Comment: I'm not sure that there could be a good use, given that by definition the loop is infinite and will never stop, thus draining all resources away until the program crashes.

Comment: Something that fires on an interval can be considered as an infinite loop with a sleep in it. I'd argue that your system clock is an infinite loop and I find it fairly useful.

Comment: Good infinite loop: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop
Bad infinite loop: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting

Comment: Hopefully only specific instances of infinite loops are taught as bad, not all of them.

Comment: In many languages, when a variable goes out of scope, the associated memory gets freed, and, in a loop, every iteration will end with all variables going out of scope, so for most simple infinite loops, memory shouldn't keep increasing (I assume this is what you meant by 'peaks'). There more complex things like manually allocating memory and increasing size variables (e.g. containers) declared outside the loop, which will obviously cause memory to keep increasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the word "infinite" in this phrase should be taken a bit more loosely. I am presuming you are talking about a `while (true)` loop with a `break` instruction, which *will* eventually end, as opposed to a loop which will run until the end of time and all humanity.

In the former sense, yes, there *are* use cases where it's appropriate:

- Games use infinite [game loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure).
- Embedded programs use infinite [main loops](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems/Super_Loop_Architecture).
- Windows applications use infinite [message loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows).

One example where they might be used inappropriately is when they are used to create time delays by spinning the CPU, which is what novice programmers tend to do to avoid dealing with timer interrupts (or timer events, or other non-procedural constructs). However, when spinning the CPU is done to acquire a shared resource, then the "infinite loop" is also a perfectly valid implementation choice. Even the .NET CLR Monitor, for example, tries [spinning for several hundred cycles](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2013/07/12/lock-vs-mutex.aspx) before issuing a true wait on a kernel event handle and creating a more expensive thread switch.

Answer (score 6):

Basicly every operating system or server spins in an infinte loop.

To avoid these memory issues normally you wouldn't allocate memory inside the loop unless it can be freed later inside the same loop. For example you would allocate memory for a request and delete it once it was served.

To avoid cpu peaks you would wait for interrupts in case of an os or call a blocking function like poll() which waits for a new event once per iteration.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to programs that run on event loops (like the the system processes that @Christoph mentions), some languages have a concept known as a [generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29), that allow and even encourage you to write an infinite loop. The trick is that the object only runs for a finite time when it "yields" (returns) some expression. After that its state is "frozen"  until it is needed again. For example, in Python you can have an object that alternates between `LEFT` and `RIGHT`:

```
def side():
    while True:
        yield "LEFT"
        yield "RIGHT"

a = side()
print a.next()
print a.next()
print a.next()
```

Which would give `LEFT RIGHT LEFT`. The `side` function looks like an infinite loop with the statement `While True:`, but it will only ever run for a finite amount of time per call.

Answer (score 0):

All the applications on your handset run in infinite event loops.